# Sampling efficiently conditioned on linear constraints modulo both $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Given a prime $p$ and positive integer $t \ll \log p$ (say $t = \sqrt{\log p}$), is there an  algorithm that is polynomial time in $\log p$ to sample uniform $X, Y \in \mathbb{F}_p$ conditioned on the following constraints:

1) For some $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$, $$X Y = a \mod p.$$
2) Express $X$ as a bitstring $X_1 \ldots X_{\lceil \log p\rceil}$ using the binary representation. Then the $\lceil \log p\rceil$ binary random variables so obtained lie in a given subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^{\lceil \log p \rceil}$ of dimension $\lceil\log p\rceil - t$.

3) Same condition as 2) for $Y_i$'s.

I will be happy to get any pointers or reference for this. Even some intuition on why this might or might not be true will be helpful.